# Взять содержимое с страницы json

Tags: php, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой массив данных:

```
{
  "result":"ok",
  "contactId":"9563",
  "contactCode1c":"",
  "contactNamefull":"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434",
  "contactName":"\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434",
  "contactNamelast":"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442",
  "contactNamemiddle":"",
  "contactCompany":"",
  "contactCompanyID":0,
  "contactEmail":"",
  "contactEmails":"",
  "contactPhone":"0660785767",
  "contactPhones":"",
  "contactTypesex":"",
  "contactManagerid":"3963",
  "contactCdate":"2018-04-16 17:18:16",
  "contactPost":"",
  "contactSourceId":"0",
  "contactAdress":"",
  "contactCountry":"",
  "contactRegion":"",
  "contactDistrict":"",
  "contactCity":"",
  "contactStreet":"",
  "contactStreetNumber":"",
  "contactApartment":"",
  "contactSourceName":"",
  "contactPricelevel":false,
  "contactAuthorid":"3963",
  "contactCurrency":"UAH",
  "customFieldArray":[
    {
      "key":"Kolichestvobalov",
      "value":"200"
    }
  ],
  "legalArray":[]
}
```

contactid вывожу таким кодом:

```
//адрес сайта
 $url = 'http://site.ru';
// получаем содержимое сайта
 $json = file_get_contents($url);
// преобразуем в массив
 $array = json_decode($json, true);
// выводим значение переменной contactId
 echo $array['contactId'];
```

Вопрос такой, как вывести значение 200 этой строки?

```
{"key":"Kolichestvobalov","value":"200"}
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто получить то так:

```
echo $array['customFieldArray'][0]['value'];
```

А можно циклом получать, ибо `customFieldArray` является массивом, тогда все `value` выводить так:

```
foreach ($array['customFieldArray'] as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($value['value']);
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, а если будет так {"key":"Kolichestvobalov","value":"200"} {"key":"Kolichestvobalov2","value":"400"} как быть тогда?

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин второй способ в ответе, перебет все `value`

Comment: подскажите а если нужно вывести только {"key":"Kolichestvobalov2","value":"400"} а не {"key":"Kolichestvobalov","value":"200"} {"key":"Kolichestvobalov2","value":"400"}

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин есть второй элемент, то `[1]`

Comment: спасибо большое, вопрос закрыт.